# Error message "No distribution are installed" in Visual Studio Community 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I'm facing an issue with Visual Studio Community 2022, I've 3 projects in my solution. All projects have target framework .NET 3.0.

1. Web Application(UI)
2. Web Application(API)
3. Class Library

I've set projects 1 and 2 as startup projects.

But now when I'm trying to run the project API project gets run successfully, but UI project not running, for the UI project Visual Studio giving an error.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Seemly you must install a linux OS on PC.

Comment: Why do I need to install linux on my PC ?

Comment: Windows OS have reach supported. when we talk about Microsoft Technologies compared to another os.

Comment: Try checking to see if you have a properties/laucnhSettings.json file. I opened a solution in VS2022 and this file was added automatically (or maybe the first time I tried to debug the project). When it was added, it only had a WSL option which was why VS2022 was trying to use WSL. I deleted launchSettings.json and debugging the project now works like it does on my other machine with VS2022.

Comment: Yes, I've resolved the issue by adding Launch Profile.

Comment: I had a simple Windows Console app written to do some database reads. Framework: .NET Core 3.1.  It ran fine F5'd out of Visual studio until I upgraded from VS 2019 to VS 2022.  launchSettings.json was the issue for me too. VS 2022 either added it or used it whereas 2019 didn't. There was only one entry, which specified WSL. I deleted the entire file and all is back to normal.

Answer (score 9):

Faced a similar issue and was able to resolve this in a 2 step process

1. Deleted the file launchSettings.json
2. Installed the compatible framework (in my case .NETCore 3.1.0)

Detailed Error message when receiving "Error Launching.."

"It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '3.1.0' (x64) was not found.

- The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK."

Answer (score 3):

I encountered similar error after accidentally deleting the default debug profile in console application. After comparing the original files with changed one I found Visual Studio created root\Properties\launchSettings.json file with one entry. After reverting the changes back(by removing the launchSettings.json file) the error message disappered

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If, like me, you're searching for the solution this problem while thinking you don't have a `launchSettings.json`: verify that it isn't for sure caused by a `launchSettings.json` file under the project's `Properties` directory.

I thought I didn't have this file, but I had started VS as Administrator which did create the file suddenly but I wasn't aware of it since it was ignored in my `.gitignore` file! Deleting this `launchSettings.json` fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

I removed the WSL entry in launchSettings.json profiles and made sure the one entry I had was for the application.

"profiles" {
"NameOfProject" : {
"commandName": "Project"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this issue by creating a new profile:

1. Click the down arrow next to execute button (WSL)
2. Click Console Debug Properties
3. Create a new profile
4. Browse your project's directory
5. Close the tab
6. Click the down arrow again
7. Select Profile